# Example with Yoneda Lemma

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

This question refers to an example illustrating properties of the Yoneda lemma:
[Basic Example of Yoneda Lemma?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030418/basic-example-of-yoneda-lemma)

Here the paragraph of matter in my question:

[image]

By Definition the Yoneda lemma provides a bijection between $Hom(Hom_{C}(-,A), F) $ and $F(A)$, so in this case $Hom(Hom_{M}(-,*), \phi) \cong \phi(*)$.

How do we conclude here that YL provedes the identification of a $M$-action $\phi$ (defined above as functor $M \to Set$) with a function $h: M \to \phi(*)$ with the rule $h(m_1m_2) = \phi(m_1)(h(m_2))$? I don't see where does it come.

Comment: What is $A^*$? Not sure if it matters, but it is a bit confusing.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be true. If and $M$-action is on $A$ and on $B$, then there is an $M$-action on $A\sqcup B$. Which map $M\to A\sqcup B$ is this $h$?

Comment: So if $\eta \in Hom(Hom_{M}(-,*), \phi)$ in natural trafo, so you mean that $h = \eta_*(id_*)$ (by def of Yoneda isomorphism)? Indeed, both a maps $M \to \phi(*)$. But why $h(m_1m_2) = \phi(m_1)(h(m_2))$ holds?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be true. If there is an $M$-action on $A$ and on $B$, then there is an $M$-action on $A\sqcup B$. Which map $M\to A\sqcup B$ is this $h$?

The Yoneda lemma here says that each $x\in \phi(\star)$ there is a unique map $h_x:M\to \phi(\star)$ so that $h_x(m_1m_2)=\phi(m_1)h_x(m_2)$. That is, $h_x$ is a natural transformation from $\phi$ to $\hom_{M}(-,*)$. This map is $h_x(m)=\phi(m)(x).$

This in turn means that $\phi$ is equivalent to an $h:M\times X\to X$ with the usual definition of an action: $h(m_1,h(m_2,x))=h(m_1m_2,x).$ and $h(1,x)=x$.

Comment: You are correct. I did make a mistake there and write down not what I intended. The $x$ is needed to even make the correspondence to the right fold work. Thanks.